# How do i Fix this NaN

Tags: javascript, html, performance, datatables

whenever i call for the inputs made inside the table they end being NaN and it then cause all of my code to crash please check out the image attached to this post to get a full picture of what i am talking about, I even went forward to do more and when I call for the input made for user for calculations it gave the html input element instead of the inputted values the user made

whenever i call for the input in the table i get what you see

```js
let $unitload1 = document.getElementById("unitload1");
let $unitload2 = document.getElementById("unitload2");

let $unitload111 = parseInt($unitload1.value);
let $unitload222 = parseInt($unitload2.value);

//grade tables
// const $selectedGrade;
let grading1 = document.getElementById("courseGrade1");
let grading2 = document.getElementById("courseGrade2");

const $gpa = document.getElementById("gpaprint");
const check1 = "yes ooo";
console.log($unitload111, $unitload222);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">cve 445</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">RAW MATERIALS</div>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" id="unitload1" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="courseGrade1" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">cve 945</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">RAW MATERIALS</div>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" id="unitload2" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="courseGrade2" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Consider using `valueAsNumber` instead of parsing the value

Comment: I made you a snippet. If you console.log the .value instead of the element you do not get NaN

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's still saying NaN

Comment: @Mmerichukwu what is? The example in the question doesn’t  produce NaN

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Number in place of parseInt to cast the String value to number. Example:

```
let $unitload222 = Number($unitload2.value);
```

Comment: They're already doing this. Except across two lines.